Beveling and bevel bodifier
I have applied mesh and also scale and location of my model is zero still after applying bevel modifier it is not showing any effect of beweling ,i also gone to edit mode selecting all and tried to bevel through ctrl+ b it is destroying the model

Hello also recalculate the normals in Edit mode (Shift N), but maybe show a screenshot or even share your file
